# Parsing ZonedDateTime independently on local timezone

Tags: java, timezone, java-time, date

I am trying to parse ZonedDateTime (or Instant) without having to go through LocalDate, which is influenced with local timezone.

I would like to be able to do something like:

```
val string = "2020-02-02T10:00:00"
val timeZone = ZoneId.of("Europe/Vienna")
val zoned = ZonedDateTime.parse(string, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME, timeZone)
```

However there is not even any similar method - all the methods require using of `LocalDate`, which unfortunately yields different results when having different local timezone. I want to completely ignore local timezone and be able to create ZonedDateTime or Instant just from given parameters.

Comment: Correction: `LocalDate` is without time zone and in no way influenced by local time zone. It just has a confusing name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The input string you have just represent local date time, so first parse it into `LocalDateTime` and then convert it into `ZoneDateTime` at zone, I would not say `Instant` because it always represent the instant in UTC

```
ZonedDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(string,DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
                                      .atZone(timeZone);
```

Comment: Note: could use [ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME) instead of `ofPattern` (no (big) difference)

Comment: Even simpler: The string, `2020-02-02T10:00:00`, is in ISO 8601 format. `LocalDateTime` parses this format without any explicit formatter at all. Just use `LocalDateTime.parse(string).atZone(timeZone)`.